# In android application, can we add another Row in Settings's "App info" like we can do in iOS?

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

In iOS, in app settings, developer can create switch by turning it on User can open same app in Another Mode. For example, if user using music app, user can go to System Setting, open that app and Change mode. After that when user open same music app, user will see entire different layout this time.

In android So far i didn't found anything like that. In flutter i have requirement like if user turn on Switch from app info. Next time app should show Setting page or open setting from there itself.

For reference you can check "Google Play Music"'s App info. You will see "Additional settings in the app". How did they do it? Any help will be appreciated.

I already checked https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

Comment: `In flutter i have requirement` so your question isn't really about android, right ? it's regarding flutter ? if that's the case you should make sure to use the flutter tag in your question too

Comment: Ok, however Flutter pub dev dosent have any plugin for this, So i have to work on Android Native. That is why i mention just Android. If i am able to make in Android, flutter is easy then.

Comment: i don't think there's any harm here in adding the flutter tag, you might find alternative solutions you didn't find previously

Comment: ok let me add then

Comment: i've already added it :) i was just leaving the comment to make sure you think of it in future

Comment: have you seen articles like this https://buffer.com/resources/exposing-notification-settings-to-the-android-system/ ? might be useful for what you were trying to do (I know that it is too old post :) )